# How to unnest tibble after group_nest?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is code that gathers some data by some grouping columns:

```
df <- tibble(data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(4,5,6)))
vars <- c('x', 'y')
df2 <- df %>%
    group_nest(grouping_=across(all_of(vars))) %>%
    mutate(result=1, data=NULL) %>%
    unnest(cols=result)
```

Now df2 has a grouping_ column of data frames with two elements (x and y):

```
> str(df2)
tibble [3 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ grouping_: tibble [3 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ x: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ y: num [1:3] 4 5 6
 $ result   : num [1:3] 1 1 1
```

How do I flatten out df2 to have a data frame with three columns (x, y, result)?

I could not get unnest to work:

```
> unnest(df2, cols=grouping_)
Error: Assigned data `map(data[[col]], as_df, col = col)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 3 rows.
x Assigned data has 2 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

I'm using tidyverse 1.3.0, hence dplyr 1.0.0.

**EDIT**: Here's a hacky way:

```
cbind(df2$grouping_,
      df2 %>% mutate(grouping_=NULL))
```

Maybe that's the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `summarize()` instead of `unnest()`.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_nest(grouping_=across(all_of(vars))) %>%
  mutate(result=1, data=NULL) %>% 
  summarize(grouping_, result)

df2 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y result
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     4      1
2     2     5      1
3     3     6      1

str(df2)
tibble [3 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ x     : num [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ y     : num [1:3] 4 5 6
 $ result: num [1:3] 1 1 1
```